# Copy image URL to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my code is working well but it have simple problem, if you click once the code will work, but if you removed the input value and try again to click on the image the code will not work:

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="club">
        <img src="https://cdn-s3.si.com/s3fs-public/2018/07/10/cristiano-ronaldo-juventus-deal.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="club">
        <img src="https://cdn-s3.si.com/s3fs-public/2018/07/10/cristiano-ronaldo-juventus-deal.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>    
</div>

$('.images .club img').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.ajax #image').removeAttr('value').attr('value', $imageUrl);
});
```

Comment: Please post HTML too. Anyway, you should use `.val()` to set the value, instead of removing the `value` attribute and adding it again.

Comment: if you could share a https://jsfiddle.net/ link, we could help faster.

Comment: Don't use `removeAttr()` and `attr()` to set the value of the element. Just use `val()`. I'm not 100% certain this is the cause of your issue without seenig a working example, which is why I haven't provided it as an answer, but it certainly won't be helping

Comment: this problem may be occurring due to no change in the input field since. So reset your form instead clearing the input field.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did this before but nothing

Comment: @31piy I added it

Comment: @ymutlu
okay thank you I will share it now

Comment: @John I post answer before you update but hope it helps.. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` instead of `attr`

```js
$('.images.club img').click(function (e) {
    $('.text').val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text"/>
<div class="images club">
<img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**To your edit with your code**

```js
$('.images .club img').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ajax #image').val( $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```css
img{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax">
<input id="image"/>
</div>
<div class="images">
    <div class="club">
        <img src="https://cdn-s3.si.com/s3fs-public/2018/07/10/cristiano-ronaldo-juventus-deal.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="club">
        <img src="https://cdn-s3.si.com/s3fs-public/2018/07/10/cristiano-ronaldo-juventus-deal.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,
could you explain me the reason and why my code didn't work?
thank you very much

Comment: it because when you delete value from input the value not really removed see in source in F12 and see that the value attribute stay with the  src value even you delete it (delete by your self not by code)

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: Happ to help:) :)

Answer (score 0):

Added solution to fiddle, you can use .val() function to update input field.

```
$('.images .club img').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#image').val($imageUrl);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mdvq94c0/10/